# onblur ajax get multiple form field values from array

Tags: php, ajax, forms, onblur

Hi i have a very tiny problem. I am using ajax call to fetch values onblur of customer id. I am able to get one value in form but i want multiple values to fill form fields. my partial code is as follows:

```
req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange; 
req.open("GET", url + '?mob=' + number, true); 
req.send(null); 

function processReqChange() {

    if (req.readyState == 4) { 

        if (req.status == 200) { 
            document.getElementById('oper').value = req.responseText;
                               }
                             }
                            }
```

My php code for sending the data:

```
$f = fopen('file.csv', "r");
    $result = false;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($f)) {
        if ($row[0] == $mob) {
            $result = $row[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo $result;
```

How should i send multiple values like $row[2], $row[3] to fill form fields like username, email etc.
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way would be to have PHP return a JSON string and parse that in JS.

Example in PHP (nothing dynamic here):

```
echo '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}';
```

Then using that in JS:

```
var result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
// now you can use the values returned by PHP
alert(result.key1);
```

For more info on how to produce JSON with PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/book.json.php

Please note that this example is highly primitive. You might want to add more JSON sanity/validity checks in the JS code and, of course, a more elegant PHP generation.

Comment: thnks i have tried like this, but i am still getting only $result[1] value in form not $result[2] `var result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
document.getElementById('oper').value = result[1];
document.getElementById('state').value = result[2];`